# How do I make my blog's mobile homepage to recognize my CSS implementations?

Tags: css, mobile

I attempt to streamline my site for mobile users. I have implemented adjustments that target mobile by adding css under **@media screen and (max-width: 480px)**.

I was successful but only on all post pages. Homepage won't follow the css rule that I've made which works on all post pages.

[This is a post page screenshot **before css is added**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T25VL.png) and [this is its screenshot **after I added the css**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43juj.png) Meanwhile, this is [the homepage screenshot **before**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh86d.png) and [**after**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCUDv.png) css is added. The homepage hasn't changed after I added my css implementations.

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
.header-logo {width: 62%; float:left; margin-left: 58px;}
.navigation-item {margin-left: -15px;}
.hometab {height: 42px; padding-top:4px;}
.main-navigation-items {position: relative; width: 97%; height: 32px; margin-top:-27px;}
.main-social {height: 20px; display: inline-block;}
.mainfl {height: 42px; padding-top: 0;}
i.fa-plus-square {size:500px;  margin-top:-40px;}
i.fa-facebook-square {display: none;}
i.fa-google-plus-square {display: none;}
i.fa-twitter-square {display: none;}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='header-logo' id='header-brand'>
<div class='navigation-item'>
    <ul class='main-navigation-items top-menu' id='main-navigation-items'>
        <li><a class='hometab' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><i class='fa fa-home'/> Home</a></li>

                <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;http://fourthblogtester.blogspot.com/?m=1&quot;'>
         <ol class='main-social'>
            <li><a class='mainfb' href='#' itemprop='url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Facebook'><i class='fa fa-facebook-square'/></a></li>
            <li><a class='maingp' href='#' itemprop='url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Google+'><i class='fa fa-google-plus-square'/></a></li>
            <li><a class='maintw' href='#' itemprop='url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Twitter'><i class='fa fa-twitter-square'/></a></li>
            <li><a class='mainfl' href='#' itemprop='url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Follow Us'><i class='fa fa-plus-square'/>Follow</a></li>
         </ol>
      </b:if>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I appreciate all your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is <ok> supposed to be <ol>? If so, the structure of your HTML is not correct.

Comment: I'm sorry it's just a typo. Yes, it's <ol> and I've corrected it. Thanks. The issue still persists.

Comment: Well, it still contains the error: an <ol> directly inside an <ul> is not allowed; <ul>s can only contain <li>s as children. So what you see is the result of the browser's error handling at work. Anyway, but to address your question, I put your code in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epsfgLoz/) and it does behave differently below 480px width than above. (Neither display looks much like your screenshots though.)

Comment: To be honest, my template is a custom blogger template from a provider and I'm just modifying its layout so that it becomes more user friendly. The <ok> was used by the template's web developer. Well, your last statement has kinda surprised me. Any suggestion?

Comment: Since the source you provided does not demonstrate the issue, can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll do that and get back here as soon as it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, after so much trials & errors. [Before, it looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGt8Z.png) and [**NOW** it looked like **this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzaK5.png).

**Here are the tweaks that I employed**

I looked into the CSS section. In my template there are two sets of css implementations for general layout, namely **Global Responsive** and **CSS Item Responsive**.

I copied the css that I created under CSS Item Responsive, code of which is below:

```
/* CSS Item Responsive */

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
h1.post-title {font-size: 20px;
   margin-top: -20px;}
.header-logo {width: 62%;
   float:left;
   margin-left: 58px;}
.homepage .mobile-menu .hamburger{
   float: left;
   margin-left: -15px;}
html, body {max-width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;}
.post-body {width: 108%;
   text-align: justify;
   text-justify: inter-word;
   margin-left: -20px;
   margin-right: 5px;}
.navigation-item {margin-left: -15px;}
.hometab {height: 42px; padding-top:4px;}
.main-navigation-items {position: relative; width: 99%;
   height:32px; margin-left: -6px;
   margin-top:-27px;}
.main-social {height:20px;display: inline-block;}
.mainfl {height: 42px;padding-top: 0;}
i.fa-plus-square {size:500px;;margin-top:-40px;}
i.fa-facebook-square {display: none;}
i.fa-google-plus-square {display: none;}
i.fa-twitter-square {display: none;}
}
```

I pasted above code right under Global Responsive. The navigation bar corrected its width and centered itself. Still, these errors existed:

1. 'Follow' tab fell below half the black navbar.
2. Black navbar got down its right position.
3. Header logo still oversized.
4. Elements of each post-summary overlapped one another.
5. Entire post summary was truncated on the right of mobile browser.

So, I tweaked repeatedly and made adjustments on properties' values until I get the perfect layout. Furthermore, I deleted handful of CSS syntax as required. Post summary css syntax must be added as well.

Here's the final code:

```
/* Global Responsive */

.header-logo {width: 62%!important;
   float:left!important;
   margin-left: 58px!important;}
.homepage .mobile-menu .hamburger{
   float: left;
   margin-left: -15px;}
html, body {max-width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;}
.post-summary p {width: 108%;
   margin-left: -20px!important;
   margin-right: 5p!important;}
.navigation-item {margin-left: -15px;}
.hometab {height: 42px; padding-top:4px;}
.main-navigation-items {position: relative; width: 99%;
   height:32px; margin-left: -5px;
   margin-top:-27px!important;}
.main-social {height:20px;display: inline-block;}
.mainfl {height: 42px;padding-top: 0;}
i.fa-plus-square {size:500px;;margin-top:-40px;}
i.fa-facebook-square {display: none;}
i.fa-google-plus-square {display: none;}
i.fa-twitter-square {display: none;}
}
```